# How do I know how much traffic my wordpress/buddypress based social media website could hold? What to do when traffic goes up?

Tags: traffic, buddypress

Right now I'm paying 5 dollars a month for hosting to godaddy.com. Although there are no users registered yet (it's closed for maintenance mode as I'm testing and buiding it), it's slower than e.g. facebook. Does anyone have experience on using buddypress? What happens if my site blows up and draws a lot of users very fast. I guess I can get more expensive and better quality hosting, but is there a limit for buddypress based sites, especially when I'm using quite a few plugins.

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress scales quite high, so the code itself won't be a problem, even with tens of thousands of users. Your problems will probably be imposed by your host--limiting database transactions or sizes of tables--or specific themes taking a long time to render.

Firebug can be a great tool to use if you want to identify what component is causing a site to be slow. [Instructions on using Firebug](http://www.paulspoerry.com/2007/diagnose-slow-wordpress-performance-using-firebug/)